# What is the meaning for .= (dot + =) in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl scripting, so can anyone please let me know what is the meaning for .= in perl scripting. Will the data will be appended to that variable?

Input file has 
1
2
3

Using loop access the file and write the variable.

I see the corresponding value are assigned like below.

```
$a .= $ipval
```

So please let me know what does `.=` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the value is concatenated to the variable on left.

Essentially

```
$a .= $ipval
```

Is the same as:

```
$a = $a . $ipval
```

Comment: Not quite the same.  If $a is undef, . will warn and .= will not